# Undesired outline appearing on transparent border in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, cross-browser, border

I have set up an example at http://jsfiddle.net/ngChu/

When using a `div:after` selector and using a border that has a transparent colour on the top and bottom, Firefox seems to create an undesired outline. This outline is not visible in Safari/Chrome.

**EDIT:** The desired look is to see no outline.

I've seen a few related posts to this issue, but I'm wondering whether there may be a better solution to my specific problem.

Comment: first, the border does not have a semi-transparent color, you're simply setting the top-bottom to transparent, and the left-right to white. second - this method relies on a vendor specific rendering and is not recommended. to create reliable shadows you better set the `:after` element to display as block level, and set its width and height to the same values as its preceding container, than set its background color and give it a slight offset.

Answer (score 1):

try the [edited jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ngChu/6/), by my recommended technique described in the comment.

Comment: Thanks for that. Sorry if I wasn't clear enough, but that's not exactly what I'm try to do. For the purpose of this demonstration I want the same shapes as in the fiddle I posted, but I don't want to be able to see the shadow.

Comment: my bad, i see now you are trying to get rid of the shadow.. please let me know what are you trying to do, in the broader sense - what is the purpose of these shapes? plus - what version of firefox are you using?

Comment: Take a look at this link http://nicolasgallagher.com/pure-css-speech-bubbles/demo/ I've made some speech bubbles like the ones with the thick green border about half way down the page. If you look closely on Firefox you can see a shadow where the small bit of the speech bubble joins the rest of the bubble.

Comment: take a look at [my speech bubbles on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eliranmal/55yqG/), no 'shadow' on FireFox.

Comment: Thanks, but I've managed to reduce the damage the shadow does by changing the size of the :after border. Do you have any idea why the shadow was appearing?

Comment: it seems FF doesn't handle overlapping border widths so well, try looking it up at [quirks mode](http://www.quirksmode.org/), anyway - please post the solution so everyone can enjoy it.